# how to detect the end of an external SWF (SWF PPT, Captivate AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external

I'm having a small (big) problem, need to know exactly when actions take place in an external SWF, but not a common but a SWF SWF exported from Captivate, I've created a function that loads and transforms it into MC, but the *totalFrames* use the function, the number 30 is always the same SWF not ending in frame 30, as knowing that the swf was finalized?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about end of external SWFs animation, you could add frame script to the last frame making it dispatch an event that would notify you that the animation is over.

More about adding frame script: http://www.as3dp.com/2009/09/a-closer-look-using-movieclipaddframescript/

More on dispatching events: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html

Comment: For my example, unfortunately did not work, but thanks for the help!